# Usages of Look vs Looks

Tags: sentence-choice, sentence-usage

Just wondering if these sentences are correct.

"All these rocks looks the same." (Potentially an informal usage? Like saying anyways instead of anyway??)
"All these rocks kind of look the same."

Answer (score 1):

You definitely need 'look', not 'looks', with a plural subject.

'Kind of' is not grammatically wrong, but it is a poor word choice. Better would be:

> All the rocks look much the same.